# Avoid unexpected behavior using namerefs in bash

Tags: bash

Why does this give no output (other than newline) instead of "foo"?  The code uses a *nameref*, which was introduced in bash 4.3, and is a "reference to another variable" which "allows variables to be manipulated indirectly."

And what should be done to guard against this, if writing code for a library?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

setret() {
   local -n ret_ref=$1
   local ret="foo"
   ret_ref=$ret
}

setret ret
echo $ret
```

Running it through `bash -x` made my head spin, because it looks like it should be outputting the `foo` that I expected:

```
+ setret ret
+ local -n ret_ref=ret
+ local ret=foo
+ ret_ref=foo
+ echo
```

---

Interestingly, this prints `bar`, not `foo`.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

setret() {
   local -n ret_ref=$1
   ret_ref="bar"
   local ret="foo"
   ret_ref=$ret
}

setret ret
echo $ret
```

With an equally confusing `bash -x` output:

```
+ setret ret
+ local -n ret_ref=ret
+ ret_ref=bar
+ local ret=foo
+ ret_ref=foo
+ echo bar
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping this is valuable to others, because asking for the expected output in the `#bash` IRC channel got a response from one of its regulars of `foo`, which is what I expected.

Then, they set me straight.  *namerefs* just don't work like I thought they did.  `local -n` isn't setting `ret_ref` to refer to `$1`.  Rather, it basically storing the string `ret` in `ret_ref`, marked to be used as a reference when it's used.

So, although it looked to me like `ret_ref` would refer to the caller's `ret` variable, it only does so until the function defines its own local `ret` variable, then it will refer to that one instead.

The only guaranteed way to guard against this, if writing code for a library, is within any function that uses *namerefs*, to prefix all non-nameref variables with the function name, along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

setret() {
   local -n ___setret_ret_ref=$1
   local ___setret_ret="foo"
   ___setret_ret_ref=$___setret_ret
}

setret ret
echo $ret
```

Very ugly, but necessary to avoid collisions.  (Sure, there's less ugly ways to do it that might be likely to work, but not as certain.)